# Unable to establish communication between API and WEB service in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I am trying my hands-on on Docker and am a newbie to this technology. Here's an issue I am stuck since long:
I have an application composed of `DJango` REST Framework, `Angular` and `MySQL` as database. I am trying to dockerize each of these component and execute using `docker-compose`
Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    volumes:
      - mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql

  api:
    build:
        context: ./api
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    volumes:
      - /api36:/home/api/api36
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
    depends_on:
      - db

  ui:
    build:
        context: ./ui
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /ui:/ui
    container_name: ui
    ports:
      - "4201:4201"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  mysql_db:
```

I updated `settings.py` file to point to `db` as `HOST` in `DATABASES`, so I am able to have a communication between my DB and API calls.
However, when I load the UI I face a failure saying: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I had added `serviceUrl` as `http://api:8010/` in my `environment.ts` file. As `api` is name of my API service, I expected that `docker-compose` will establish communication internally, but looks like I am missing something. Also, I am able to get the expected behavior when I add `ip` of the machine in `environment.ts` file.
Can someone please help me out on this?
The way I bring up and execute all the containers is `docker-compose up`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `api` name is only useable on the Docker bridge network that your containers run on. Your UI runs in a browser outside the bridge network, so you can't use the `api` name there. You have to use a name that resolves to the host machine. When developing, `localhost` works since the browser runs on the host machine. When you deploy your containers, you need to use the name of the machine hosting the containers.

Comment: Then how is `api` able to connect to `db`, there as well I have used name of service rather than `ip`

Comment: That's because both the `api` and the `db` container are on the Docker bridge network that is created when you run `docker-compose up`. You can read more about how it works here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/